# Insert object into value with different base type (inherited) c#

Tags: c#, generics, .net-2.0

So I have have an object of type [`SvgElement`](https://github.com/vvvv/SVG/blob/master/Source/SvgElement.cs) that contains a value of [`SvgPath`](https://github.com/vvvv/SVG/blob/master/Source/Paths/SvgPath.cs)(which inherits `SvgElement`). Here's the code.

```
SvgElement createdElement;
//other operations. createdElement now has other data of SvgPath

if (createdElement.GetType() == typeof(SvgPath) & createdElement.ElementName == "path" && storedValue != "")
 createdElement.PathData = SvgPathBuilder.Parse(storedValue);

return createdElement
```

(Note: this is being done in unity, .net 2.0 must be taken into consideration as Unity takes offence to System.Linq)

Now `SvgPathBuilder.Parse` takes a `string` and returns an object of type [`SvgPathSegmentList`](https://github.com/vvvv/SVG/blob/master/Source/Paths/SvgPathSegmentList.cs) into `PathData`. `PathData` is normally a variable within `SvgPath`, but I modified `SvgElement` to temporarily take the value so I would know if something else I was testing would work.

Now that I've given you the background info..How do I (generic code- Type T stuff) write it so that `SvgPathBuilder.Parse` will be stored in SvgPath.PathData rather than the inherited base SvgElement's PathData?

(not sure if title fits question, please advise)

Comment: how about casting: `(createdElement as SvgPath).PathData = SvgPathBuilder.Parse(storedValue);`

Comment: Works. You deserve a cookie.

Comment: You were talking about generics, and settled for simple casting, nonetheless do a Null reference check, which is the most probable issue in this case. If it is not assigned valid memory / initialization, then there will be Null reference exception

Comment: @MrinalKamboj I wasn't sure if a simple generic method would do the trick inside of of the classes as they are. Also, storedvalue is initialized so even if the value that should go there doesn't, it will return an empty SvgPathSegmentList.

Comment: ok, posted it as an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not very clear what are you trying to achieve from mere description, but consider following design, which still need further changes to suit exact requirements

Important details:

- SvgElement made abstract with abstract property that needs to be implemented by the Child, i.e. SvgPath
- Generic constraints used in the TestSVG to ensure, we always supply the correct class or its derived version, in this class you can implement the filling of property PathData

  ```
      public abstract class SvgElement
      {
        public abstract List<SvgPath> PathData { get; set;}
      }

      public class SvgPath : SvgElement
      {
        public override List<SvgPath> PathData { get; set;}       
      }

      public class TestSvg<T> where T:SvgElement
      {

      }
  ```

Comment: It's not what I'm looking for now, as I'm just jury-rigging the code, but when I come back to rewrite the code, this will be useful. Thank you.

Comment: This need to be further improvised based on exact use case, currently it's a rough format base on my understanding from the question

Comment: My apologies for the misunderstanding, I've been working on this for a while (other parts of it) and needed a fix that just fixed. Too many weeks on this project of mine..

Answer (score 1):

You can cast the element to SvgPath:
`(createdElement as SvgPath).PathData = SvgPathBuilder.Parse‌​(storedValue);`

Comment: It's a simple fix to an overall problem that's been eating me up. Thank you.